# Nginx 500 error page is not working with matches any unmatched URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

In my Nginx conf. error 500 rule is not working with location conf. lines below.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

error_page 500 /error.html;
location = /error.html {
  root /path/to/nginx;
  internal;
}

location @rewrite{
  rewrite ^ /index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

The error.html file is in /path/to/nginx directory. 
When I create a 500 error in the code, it couldn't run the Nginx 500 rule.
If I remove the location / { part, and change 500 to 404, it works.

Edit:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;

   server_name_in_redirect off;
   port_in_redirect off;
   server_tokens off;

   server_name  www-dev.somc.io;
   root         /path/to/site;
   index        index.php index.html index;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   rewrite_log on;

   error_page 500 /error.html;
   location = /error.html {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       internal;
   }

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
   }

   location @rewrite{
       rewrite ^ /index.php?q=$uri;
   }

   add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

   set $skip_cache 0;
   set $cache_control max-age=660;

   location ~ \.php$ {

       include /etc/nginx/php-handler.conf;

       fastcgi_pass hhvm;
    }
 }
```

Comment: post entire file along with server {}